# equivalence for spectrum of self-adjoint operator

Tags: operator-theory

How can we prove the statement ?

If $A=A^*$ then forall $a \in \mathbb{R} $ :

$A - a \geq  0 $ iff $ \sigma (A)  \subseteq [a, \infty)$

reference theorem 2.18
[https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-schroe/schroe.pdf](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Egerald/ftp/book-schroe/schroe.pdf)

Comment: There is not even a question in your post.

Comment: it would either be true or false. It is true

Comment: Mind showing what you tried? What your definition of $A-a \ge 0$ is?

Comment: $<Ax -ax ,x> \geq 0$ 
If you see in the reference this is a substatement of the theorem. 
I have problem understanding the proof

Comment: maybe can use that for any self adjoint B :

$B \geq. 0$ iff $\sigma(B) \subseteq [0,\infty)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK

For any self adjoint $B$ we have $B \geq 0 $ iff $\sigma(B) \subseteq [0,\infty) $  ...

And because $B=B^*$ we know $\sigma(B) = \sigma_a (B) $ (the RHS is the aprroximate spectrum $= \{l \in \mathbb{C}   :  \forall \epsilon >0 \exists (x_n) : A(x_n) - lx_n \to 0 \})$

So we have  $A - a \geq 0 $ iff $ \sigma_a(A-a) \subseteq [0,\infty) $
iff $\sigma_a(A) \subseteq [a,\infty) $